# How can I create a method in my entity that accepts empty entries?

Tags: php, symfony, methods, controller, entity

I want do have the opportunity that in case no desription is added in my form, there will not be an error message. What is the correct way to this?

Here my approach:

in my Controller:

```
$entity->setDescription($data['description']) ?? null;
```

my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535)
 *
 */
private string $description;




 public function setDescription(string $description): void
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
```

the Error message:

> App\Entity\Event::setDescription(): Argument #1 ($description) must be
> of type string, null given, called in
> /src/Controller/Admin/myController.php on line 109

Comment: Try `$entity->setDescription($data['description'] ?? '');`. If `$data['description']` is null, it will instead pass in an empty string. The null coalesce operator (`??`) needs to be on the variable you're checking. Your current code will evaluate the response of the method call, not the input value.

Comment: Or alternatively set `@ORM\Column(type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)` and run a schema update with `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update` then you can do `$entity->setDescription($data['description']);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you only set `$description` type to be string but you put null in to it, so an error occurred.

You can do `$entity->setDescription($data['description'] ?? '');` to set the description to empty string if there is no description added by mean description is a null.

Or you can make `$description` can be null too by:

```php
public function setDescription(?string $description): void
{
    $this->description = $description;
}
```

In this case you need to check whether the `$description` is not null in order to be shown in HTML or somewhere.

Comment: Important: If they accept null as an argument to that method, they also need to make sure that the property `description` in the entity and the database column they store it in accepts null as value. They would also need to make sure that no other code that uses this entity don't assume the value is a string (or they can get errors further down the line when the value is used in different places)